# Reduce the size of the multiselect box

Tags: css, html, jsp, spring-mvc, multi-select

I am using a multiselect box in JSP(Spring MVC).I have Three options in the multiselect. No CSS used for the size. but I am getting the multiselect size oversized. I just need the exact size with no extra spaces in it.

Please refer below for the code:

```
<select id="test" name="test" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="test1">test1</option>
   <option value="test2">test2</option>
   <option value="test3">test3</option>
</select>
```

The output contains some space under test3 which is not required. is there a way to eliminate that extra space?

NOTE: No CSS is used with the id.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the height of the `select` via CSS?

```css
select {
  height: 45px;
 }
```

```html
<select id="test" name="test" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="test1">test1</option>
   <option value="test2">test2</option>
   <option value="test3">test3</option>
</select>
```